# Push Segue not found when testing on device but does work on simulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, segue

this problem is driving me crazy to the point of thinking this is an Xcode bug (using the recently released Version 6.0.1 (6A317)).

I have a segue set up in the storyboard and called it programmatically using the following:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ayudapls" sender:self];
```

this is the segue in the storyboard:

[image]

It works on simulators (from '4s' to '6 Plus') but testing on a device gives me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<PTKAjustesViewController: 0x14deba40>) has no segue with identifier 'ayudapls''
```

I know this approach works because I did it with the segue right next to it... I've tried Cleaning the build, deleting it from simulators & device, and multiple combinations of both (cleaning+deleting) but no luck... Please help!

.
.
.

This is the other segue that works just fine!

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"creditos" sender:self];
```

[image]

Comment: Try renaming the storyboard, and than delete the application from phone and re-install after clean build. worked for me last time.

Comment: Thank you, worked just perfect! This one really had me going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes these weird things happens if still using some old storyboard or not cleaning the previously compiled storyboard.

So renaming the storyboard, and than delete the application from phone and re-install after clean build works just fine :)